# Определение порта, к которому подключено устройство

Tags: java, port, jssc

Использую библиотеку jssc для использования COM-портов в java.
Такая ситуация: к компьютеру подключена arduino, и надо в коде определить, к какому порту она подключена.
Как это реализовать?

Comment: Нужны подробности, в частности как подключено устройство: сама ардуина простым шнурком по USB или как-то иначе.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, По шнурку. Зачем мне усложнять.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С точки зрения компьютера, Ардуина является конвертером USB->COM, обычным USB-устройством, со своими VID и PID.

Вам нужно прочитать ветку реестра, выудить оттуда VID и PID, и по ним узнать имя COM порта.

Как это делается на C++ я уволок [отсюда](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/349002/Select-a-USB-Serial-Device-via-its-VID-PID):

```
/// <summary>
/// Compile an array of COM port names associated with given VID and PID
/// </summary>
/// <param name="VID"></param>
/// <param name="PID"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
List<string> ComPortNames(String VID, String PID)
{
    String pattern = String.Format("^VID_{0}.PID_{1}", VID,PID);
    Regex _rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    List<string> comports = new List<string>();
    RegistryKey rk1 = Registry.LocalMachine;
    RegistryKey rk2 = rk1.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Enum");
    foreach (String s3 in rk2.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        RegistryKey rk3 = rk2.OpenSubKey(s3);
            foreach (String s in rk3.GetSubKeyNames())
            {             
             if (_rx.Match(s).Success)
             {
                RegistryKey rk4 = rk3.OpenSubKey(s);
                foreach (String s2 in rk4.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    RegistryKey rk5 = rk4.OpenSubKey(s2);
                    RegistryKey rk6 = rk5.OpenSubKey("Device Parameters");
                    comports.Add((string)rk6.GetValue("PortName"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return comports;
} 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> names = ComPortNames("0403", "6001");
    if (names.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (String s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            if (names.Contains(s))
                Console.WriteLine("My Arduino port is " + s);
        }
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No COM ports found");
}
```